# How to translate incoming Telnet data from external device into VB6

Tags: vb6, ascii, telnet, translate

I made a connection to a external device.
The problem is that the feedback I get right after establishing connection is kind of as ASCII code:

ÿý↑

After checking theese sites:
 
[Telnet](http://www.pcmicro.com/netfoss/telnet.html) 
[ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/) 
[Charsets](http://www.charset.org/charactersets.php?charset=us-ascii) 
[US-ASCII](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) 
[Convert](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_to_from_ascii.html)

I found out that:
ÿ is 255 which stands for IAC (Interpret as Command) and
 
ý is 253 which stands for DO and 
↑ is 24 which stands for Cancel.

To send back commands to the terminal I do this:

```
winsck.SendData Chr(255) 'IAC
winsck.SendData Chr(252) 'WONT
winsck.SendData Chr(24) 'CANCEL
```

To translate an ASCII code to a char I made the following code:

```
lblChar = Asc(txtASCII)
```

To translate a char to an ASCII code I made the following code:

```
lblASCII = Chr(txtChar)
```

I want data from the terminal and modify them, but first I have to get through this ASCII coding.

How it normally works in cmd.exe: 
I write telnet followed by the ipaddress of destination:

**telnet (ipaddress of the terminal)**

then cmd asks me for the password. After that I would be ready to write commands. Normally I write like

**lm -h**

then it would send me a lot of data. I want to do the same with my VB6 program.

After sending the terminal "IAC WON'T CANCEL" I got back:
ÿþ↑ÿû ÿûᶫÿý

As I have trying to translate it and I came to this result:

IAC - DON'T - CANCEL - IAC - WILL (space) IAC - WILL - END OF TEXT - IAC - DO

and after sending the terminal "IAC WILL CANCEL"
I got back: ÿú↑ ÿð
= "IAC - Subnegotiation of the indicated option follows - CANCEL (space) IAC - End of subnegotiation parameters"

Seriously what does it mean - what should I answer back?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally you should try to get a technical manual of the external terminal that you would like to communicate with. A first, easy step would be to search the internet for the product name and look for manuals.

Comment: I've tried to ask my staff, but he says we do not have a more detailed document on the terminal other than technical documents. It was made by my works previous partner company so it is impossible to look for it on the web - I tried :/

Comment: Looks like IAC DO LOGOUT but I'm not sure how it makes sense for a server to send that to a client.  Have you actually tried using the Windows Telnet client, and does it work as you suggest... or are you just saying that is how you *hope* it would work?

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of it. That is how it normally works in cmd.exe.

Comment: I found out something new and have edited the question and explanation.

Comment: I could have sworn you had said it was an 18, not a 24.  But anyway this seems to answer the question of whether the device is a clent or server, it is a server and it has begun nogotiating terminal-type.  I have no idea how you got that 24 means "cancel."

Comment: I got the 24 = cancel from this site: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html. I must say that I also have found out it could be type. I am actually pretty confused about it.

Comment: CAN (cancel) is the ASCII control character with the value 24.  It has nothing to do with Telnet protocol option negotiation, where this isn't an ASCII character at all but a control byte.  Context is everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your device acts as a Telnet server and you need to implement a client in VB6.

Have you looked at [Telnet Client UserControl](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?502064-VB6-Telnet-Client-UserControl) yet?

Comment: Avtually I have, but I didn't quite get it. I will try to look at it again.

Comment: I haven't seen many alternatives.  Of course there are ActiveX libraries from commercial sources you might consider.

Comment: After some time with studying all this VB6 and telnet connection thing I finally get it.
I made a client without a User Control and blended it all together with the other stuff so I had no understanding for any of it.
Of course you have to read the RFC854 first, then about the User Control. I used the User Control from the link you gave me, added some of my own code and now I have a project which communicate with the terminal!
I thank you very much for your help, I just had to understand the idea of it all first :P

Answer (score 0):

Since those looks like Telnet commands and you mention that you can get out data if you connect via Telnet I assume you'd have to write a Telnet client. I'd suggest beginning with doing a search for `telnet RFC` if you go down this route and possibly `telnet client vb6` too.

However, another alternative might be to automate a telnet client like Putty, this question might be helpful with that: [How to run a command file in PuTTY using automatic login in a command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/515601/how-to-run-a-command-file-in-putty-using-automatic-login-in-a-command-prompt)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I must say that I'm confused about what a client do and what a server do, and what my terminal should be. That might have infuence in the way I develop my project... I will try to examine it further, thank you :)